# NSolve not returning anything

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I am trying to manipulate the function $f(x)=a-b\exp(-xc)$, where $a,b$ and $c$ are parameters and $x$ my variable. I want to fix the value and gradient at $f(x=1400)$ and the value at $f(x>4000)$. Here's how I am doing it:

```
NSolve[{
  ((a - b*Exp[-c*x]) /. x -> 1400) == 0.129417,
  ((a - b*Exp[-c*x]) /. x -> 4000) == 0.26304,
  (D[(a - b*Exp[-c*x]), x] /. x -> 1400) == 0.0002219136
  }, {a, b, c}]
```

However, `NSolve` isn't returning anything and eventually fails. Is there a different function in Mathematica appropriate for this problem?

Comment: If you have some initial guess, you can use `FindRoot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works (The initial values were found by trials.).

```
FindRoot[{((a-b*Exp[-c*x]) /. x -> 1400)==0.129417,((a - b*Exp[-c*x])/.x -> 4000)==0.26304,
(D[(a - b*Exp[-c*x]), x] /. x -> 1400) == 0.0002219136}, {a,0.2}, {b, .03}, {c, .00009},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,AccuracyGoal -> 3]
```

> {a->0.26496040221501131952,b->1.3412964939715005005,c->0.0016372143267284541222}

Verification confirms it.

```
{((a - b*Exp[-c*x]) /. x -> 1400), ((a - b*Exp[-c*x]) /. 
x -> 4000), (D[(a - b*Exp[-c*x]), x] /. x -> 1400)} /.
{a -> 0.26496040221501131952, b -> 1.3412964939715005005, c -> 0.0016372143267284541222}
```

> 0.1294169999999148617, 0.2630399999999959833, 
>   0.0002219136000000732043}

Addition. The FindRoot also works with the initial values `{a, 1.}, {b, 1.}, {c, .0001}`. The initial values of `a` and `b` are taken $1$ as usually, the initial value of `c` is chosen in such awy that $1000c \approx 1$.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any initial guess that works, but it seems reasonable that a solution should exist, then rewriting the problem to solve for one fit variable at a time may also work. If there isn't a solution, this process is a fair bit more likely to show that than `FindRoot` is as well.

```
f[a_,b_,c_] := a-b Exp[-# c]& (* this defines the family of functions of f *)
```

Solve for `b` by implementing the gradient constraint at the first x point.

```
solb = First@Solve[f[a,b,c]'[x1]==g,b]
```

Solve for `a` by implementing the y value constraint at the first x point and the b constraint.

```
sola = First@Solve[f[a,b,c][x1]==y1/.solb,a]
```

Solve for `c` by implementing the y value constraint at the second x point and the previous 2 solutions.

```
solc = First@Solve[f[a,b,c][x2]==y2/.solb/.sola,c]
```

Now insert the numerical parameters:

```
params = {x1->1400,x2->4000,y1->0.129417,y2->0.26304,g->0.0002219136};
```

And expand the previous solutions:

```
nc = solc/.params;
nb = solb/.params/.nc;
na = sola/.params/.nc/.nb;
nsol = Flatten[{na,nb,nc}]
```

`nsol` should contain `{a->0.26496,b->1.3413,c->0.00163721}`.

`(f[a,b,c]/.nsol)[x]` will generate the final function in terms of x.

In my experience normally if this process would work, then `Solve` is probably able to solve a symbolic version of this problem as well, but that doesn't appear to be true in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)
```

[`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) and [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) the equations

```
eqns = {((a - b*Exp[-c*x]) /. x -> 1400) == 0.129417,
     ((a - b*Exp[-c*x]) /. x -> 4000) == 0.26304,
     (D[(a - b*Exp[-c*x]), x] /. x -> 1400) == 0.0002219136} //
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;
```

Restrict [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) to the real domain

```
(sol = NSolve[eqns, {a, b, c}, Reals][[1]]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {16.7754, {a -> 0.26496, b -> 1.3413, c -> 0.00163721}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions

```
And @@ (eqns /. sol)

(* True *)
```

Comment: The Simplify command may be omitted.

Comment: @user64494 - while it is not necessary, it makes the equations "cleaner". It is just a matter of personal preference.